# Angularjs updating data in parent scope after modal form submission

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to figure out how to update the $scope.dir in the parent scope (DirCrl) from the child scope (ModalCtrl). The view is a simple modal form with a single text input. On submit the text input is bound to mkdir.name in the child scope. The child controller makes a REST call to a database and should  update $scope.dir in the parent scope with the response data. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Code snippet below

```
app.controller('DirCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.dir = {};
$scope.mySelections = [];

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '//localhost:9090/fx/v1/dir/52cdc7304c3525ac0c5cdd3a'
})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.dir = data;
        $scope.children = data.children;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });

}]);

var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

$scope.mkdir = {
    name: 'name',
    data: {}
};

$scope.$parent.ben = 'ben01';

$scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'modal',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            mkdir: function () {
                return $scope.mkdir;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        $scope.$parent.children = $scope.mkdir.data.children;
    });
};
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http, $log, mkdir) {
$scope.mkdir = mkdir;
$scope.submit = function () {
    $log.log('name of directory to create');
    $log.log(mkdir.name);

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '//localhost:9090/fx/v1/dir/52cdcce74c358cdfe2fa2c83'
    })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

          $scope.mkdir.data = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}


$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
};
```

Answer (score 8):

CORRECTION:

In the child do something like:

```
$scope.$emit('whatevereventnameyouwant', data);
```

In the parent listen for that event:

```
$rootScope.$on('whatevereventnameyouwant', function(event, data) { console.log(data); });
```

Comment: This answer does the job in MUCH less code and complexity than does the code in the accepted answer. +1

Answer (score 5):

**Using promise (standard way)**

The standard way to return data back to the invoking controller once the modal is closed is to register a callback once the promise is resolved:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```

**Using events**

You can also dispatch an event upwards through the scope hierarchy by invoking [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit):

```
$scope.$emit(name, args);
```

The parent scope can then listen for the event by invoking [$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on):

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function(event, data) { console.log(data); });
```

When creating a new modal, it's $scope will be a child of the $rootScope by default.  When $emit() is invoked, it looks on it's own scope (i.e. the modal's $scope) for any registered listeners, invokes them (if present), then traverses the scope chain upwards until it runs out of parents.  If the parent scope isn't specified when creating the modal, calling $scope.$emit('eventName', data) will bypass the controller's scope when evaluating the scope chain.  Both the invoking controller and the modal controller can work directly with the $rootScope when calling $emit() and $on(), but you typically want to associate a modal's scope with it's invoking controller's $scope hierarchy.  To set the parent scope of the modal, set the scope parameter to $scope as following:

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    backdrop: true,
    windowClass: 'modal',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
    scope: $scope,
    resolve: {
        mkdir: function () {
            return $scope.mkdir;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to `$scope.$emit()` back up to the parent.

In the child do something like:

```
$scope.$emit('whatevereventnameyouwant', data);
```

In the parent listen for that event:

```
$scope.$on('whatevereventnameyouwant', function(event, data) { console.log(data); });
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, for the answer, unfortunately I could not get it to work with $emit(). I cannot even access data from the parent scope in the child scope. I suspect some quirk in Angular-ui modal. All the documentation I have looked at suggest that you are right though.

Comment: Same issue. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @Arkan I would try combinations of $rootScope.$emit (to go up the chain), $rootScope.$broadcast (to go down) as well as $scope.$emit, $scope.broadcast. Make sure you inject $rootScope into your controllers if you use that. I've had no trouble with using $rootScope in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the promise interface that uibModal returns you. Let's say you have a DELETE button in the modal, and when you click you remove one item from a list that is presented in the parent view (parent scope):

**MODAL CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.deleteItem = function() {
 $http.delete(...).then(function() {
   $uibModalInstance.close(true) // instead of true you can pass an object
 })
}
```

**PARENT CONTROLLER**

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: '...',
  controller: 'ModalController',
});

modalInstance.result.then(function(data) {
  // what you pass in $uibModalInstance.close(true) will be accessible here.
  if (data) {
    refreshItems();
  }
});
```