# modalService cannot talk with controller and view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

[The code at this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6FHlHIvMEg4CoxDkxs2w?p=preview) has a modal which pops up when a user clicks on a **"Click to take quiz"** button which calls a controller method that in turn calls a modal service.  **To get the plnkr to work, click anywhere in the code and press the space bar to add white space in a way that does not effect syntax.  This will trigger plnkr to re-initialize the app and make the modal pop up after you click the button.**

The problem is that the text printed in the modal does not update dynamically when `timeLeft` variable counts down.  And also, the user's button click does not update the `quizAnswer` variable.  In short, the modal is not able to talk interactively with the calling controller and view.

**What specific changes need to be made to the plnkr to get the modal text to show the dynamic countdown, and to get the modal buttons to change the value of the $scope.quizAnswer variable?**

Also, I have been carefully reading [the documentation at this link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).  I think that the answer may be related to:

1.) `$uibModal`'s `options` parameter passed in `open(options)` contains the parameter `scope` that defines the parent scope to be used for the modal's content, and also property `bindToController` which, when set to `true`, binds the `scope` property to a specific controller defined by `controllerAs`.

2.) The `open(options)` method returns a modal instance, which includes `close(result)` and `dismiss(reason)`.

I suspect that the solution lies in these methods and parameters, but I am looking for good examples and would appreciate some experienced eyes looking at this problem.

**NOTE: The solution to this came in the comments below the accepted answer, especially the link to another posting that contains 2 lines of code for emitting the modal button click's results back to the parent controller.**

Comment: I don't think this is going to be the culprit, but quickly glancing you have `$scope.$digst();` which is a typo. That being said you shouldn't need a digest to be called in an `$interval`

Comment: @dman2306 Thank you.  Also, simply fixing the typo caused the plnkr to re-initialize, which gets the modal working again.  For some reason, the modal button does not produce the modal after a while, unless you trigger a re-initialization of the app by typing a character or two.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Posting huge amount of code which is not related to problem and not working plunks are not good practice.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov As per comment above, the plnkr works when you trigger a restart, such as for example changing `digst()` to `digest()`.  Also, if you think certain aspects of the posted code are not relevant, please suggest specific edits and I will happily review them to improve the OP.  I just added something at the end of the OP showing a link to documentation with a summary of what I am finding that might be relevant.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I also added a bolded note at the top of the OP explaining how to get the modal popup to launch by creating whitespace.  I think it has to do with the `modalexists` variable getting re-set to false when the app gets re-initialized.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tCHsaEHJtNOrt2KoR8Yx?p=preview may be this will help u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of issues.

First, `takeQuiz` at navigation.js - line 16, should be attached to `$scope`, not `this`, since `this` will mutate depending on context.

Second, `$scope.$apply` and `$scope.$digst();` at navigation.js - lines 29/30 are unnecessary since you will already be in a digest cycle.  They should be removed else they'll trigger an error.

Finally (and this is the meat of your issue), you are misunderstanding how modal options are bound across when creating a modal instance.  It is NOT two-way binding; it is a single extends from one object to another.  As a result, trying to bind to the options (or creating a concatenated string with the timeRemaining) will not update once it's bound across.

Instead, one possibility is to create an event handler inside of the modal and broadcast on each tick, updating the modal.  In addition, if you pass the body text as prepend and append text, it is easier to insert your timestamp value:

You will need to inject (and broadcast from) `$rootScope` in your navigationController, since the `modalService` is registered somewhere very high in the scope chain.

On each tick, broadcast the time remaining navigation.js:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('timeRemainingTick', $scope.timeRemaining);
```

In your modalService.js, register to receive the event inside of the controller assignment:

```
var timeRemainingUnbind = $scope.$on('timeRemainingTick', function(event, newTick) {
    $scope.modalOptions.timeRemaining = newTick;
});
```

Finally, make sure that you unbind the event by calling `timeRemainingUnbind()` in the close events of your modal to prevent memory leaks:

```
$scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
    timeRemainingUnbind();
    $modalInstance.close(result);
};

$scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
    timeRemainingUnbind();
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

See my working forked plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z96YiTg4hkIIKItyd6Ec?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to educate us.  How do I get the result of the user's choice to print on the browser page?  The user chooses blue or grey, then the word blue or grey should become the `quizAnswer` variable that prints on the page.  This would enable programmatic access from the navigation controller in addition to letting the user read it.  Plus complete the resolution of this OP?

Comment: @CodeMed You're welcome.  That would be a separate question, not an extension of the same question.  If you stuck to the current modal approach, you'd probably want to emit back to your navigation service.

Comment: No worries.  The OP does state the question as **What specific changes need to be made to the plnkr to get the modal text to show the dynamic countdown, and to get the modal buttons to change the value of the $scope.quizAnswer variable?**.  However, it is not your responsibility, and I am grateful for what you have done towards this objective.  Thank you again.

Comment: @CodeMed I understand that :).  My point rather is that there is already so much content in this particular question that it is diminishing the value for others who would use it as a reference.  Expanding it further to include that additional scope would make it much less useful, whereas creating a new question specifically to address that issue with the (now) working code is more beneficial to others down the road.

Comment: In any event, I have carefully read your answer, and I have carefully compared the code in your plnkr with the code in my plnkr, making all the changes that your answer specifies, validated by checking your plnkr.  But the resulting new plnkr does not update the timer in the modal.  I will keep studying the two plnkrs, but would you be willing to look at my new one's attempt to implement your answer?  Here is the link:  http://plnkr.co/edit/6FHlHIvMEg4CoxDkxs2w?p=preview

Comment: @CodeMed You didn't update your modal options arguments.  One of the reasons for breaking out the text into three pieces (prepend, timeremaining, and append) is so that you can dynamically insert the new timeRemaining timestamp as it updates.

Comment: OK.  I changed `'modalOptions` to fit your example, but it is still not updating the timer.  Here is the further revised plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/6FHlHIvMEg4CoxDkxs2w?p=preview

Comment: You forgot to also update modalContent.html to match the new data structure.

Comment: Updating `modalContent.html` to match the new data structure got the modal to count down the remaining seconds.  Your various comments, in addition to your answer text, together describe the changes in your plnkr which got the timer to count down in the modal.

Comment: Here is a modified plunker that will update `$scope.quizAnswer` and stop the timer: http://plnkr.co/edit/au6rPf4Vhw5WkciB4DU4?p=preview

Comment: The code for getting the modal button clicks to be read by the parent controller and view is only two lines.  I will mark this answer as accepted, with the understanding that other readers will need to read all of these comments and also **READ THE 2 LINES OF CODE AT THE FOLLOWING LINK** in order to fully answer the OP's question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357115/angularjs-updating-data-in-parent-scope-after-modal-form-submission#29292260

Comment: I am very grateful for your exceeding my expectations and generously answering my question.  Nothing further is requested, as you have already been very generous.  However, if another user wants to consolidate all these comments into an edited answer, then all these comments could be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for noting and happy to help.